# Upload Visual Studio project settings in your GitHub repository

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, github, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2015

I have a Visual Studio C++ project in my GitHub repository but that repository doesn't track my project settings like:

```
Project -> Project Properties -> C/C++ -> Language -> C++ Language Standard -> std:c++latest

Set Project in Debug to Release mode

Set Arch to 64x (optional)
```

I want these settings to uploaded in GitHub repository so that when I clone that project it comes with pre-configuration.

How could I do that?